# Hide mouse cursor in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mouse-cursor

I need to hide the cross-shaped cursor that OpenCV shows when moving the mouse over an image window. Does anybody know if it is possible?

I wanted to add a screenshot, but unfortunately the mouse cursor is not shown in screenshots.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want exactly, cursor or not cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with only OpenCV, you have to use OS API or eventually you may use QT(http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/QtHideMouseCursor.php#.UjGpZD-rGoE) - it's quite easy to use it with OpenCV.

Comment: looks exactly what I want cyriel! however, I dont see the way of integrating this with my current opencv windows. How do I connect Qt with my current functions such as: namedWindow(name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); cvShowImage(name, image);

Comment: Qt is integrated with OpenCV, at least a bit - look at this http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_qt_new_functions.html Note that first you have to compile OpenCV with Qt. Google search for "opencv qt" or "opencv qt widget" gives more informations about integrating Qt and OpenCV.